# how do i properly design a worker thread? (avoid for example Sleep(1))

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++builder

i am still a beginner at multi-threading, so bear with me please:

i am currently writing an application that does some FVM calculation on a grid. it's a time-explicit model, so at every timestep i need to calculate new values for the whole grid. my idea was to distribute this calculation to 4 worker-threads, which then deal with the cells of the grid (first thread calculating 0, 4, 8... second thread 1, 5, 9... and so forth).

i create those 4 threads at program start.

they look something like this:

```
void __fastcall TCalculationThread::Execute()
{
    bool alive = true;
    THREAD_SIGNAL ts;
    while (alive)
    {
        Sleep(1);
        if (TryEnterCriticalSection(&TMS))
        {
        ts = thread_signal;
        LeaveCriticalSection(&TMS);
        alive = !ts.kill;
        if (ts.go && !ts.done.at(this->index))
        {
            double delta_t = ts.dt;
            for (unsigned int i=this->index; i < cells.size(); i+= this->steps)
            {
                    calculate_one_cell();
            }
            EnterCriticalSection(&TMS);
                thread_signal.done.at(this->index)=true;
            LeaveCriticalSection(&TMS);
        }
    }
}
```

they use a global struct, to communicate with the main thread (main thread sets ts.go to true when the workers need to start.

now i am sure this is not the way to do it! not only does it feel wrong, it also doesn't perform very well...

i read for example [here](http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.internet.winsock/200507/0507263541.html) that a semaphore or an event would work better. the answer to [this guy's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417307/maximizing-worker-thread-utilization) talks about a lockless queue.

i am not very familiar with these concepts would like some pointers how to continue.
could you line out any of the ways to do this better?

thank you for your time. (and sorry for the formatting)

i am using borland c++ builder and its thread-object (TThread).

Comment: @David: perhaps to yield thread time?! `Sleep(0)` is often used to achieve exactly the same.

Comment: Hey - someone reads my old posts!  I could upvote for that alone, but it's a bit self-serving.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you have 4 threads that should *wait* for for the main thread before `doingSomething` ? Are the thread completely independent I mean you know witch cell they'll have to compute at the beginning or do you plan to distribute the work along the time ...

Comment: First, what kind of grid?  If it's a windowed control, you should not be accessing it directly from the work threads.

Comment: @STATUS That might make sense for a busy wait but this is a blocking critical section.

Comment: @David: it's called "cargo cult programming" then. I would almost bet the original intention was to yield, though :)

Comment: sorry for being unclear:
without the Sleep(1) the threads use up cpu time for nothing. with Sleep(1) they calm down, as there are less reads i guess...

@Martin James it's a grid in the sense of a vector of structs, not a grid in the sense of a (form) control.

Comment: @vrince the main thread does other things for each step of a simulation, copies stuff around etc. only at a given point the work-threads should do their calculating. so the main-thread sets the "signal" to go. and the workers start calculating their stuff and return to doing nothing afterwards. they are completely independant in the sense, that they know what to do and how, just not exactely when.

Answer (score 2):

The definitely more effective algorithm would be to calculate yields for 0,1,2,3 on one thread, 4,5,6,7 on another, etc. Interleaving memory accesses like that is very bad, even if the variables are completely independent- you'll get false sharing problems. This is the equivalent of the CPU locking *every write*.

Comment: thanks for this contribution, i will change that and see if it makes a noticable difference.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `Sleep(1)` in a calculation thread can't be a good solution to any problem. You want your threads to be doing useful work rather than blocking for no good reason.

I think your basic problem can be expressed as a serial algorithm of this basic form:

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    cells[i]->Calculate();
```

You are in the happy position that calls to `Calculate()` are independent of each other—what you have here is a parallel for.  This means that you can implement this without a mutex.

There are a variety of ways to achieve this.  OpenMP would be one; a threadpool class another.  If you are going to roll your own thread based solution then use `InterlockedIncrement()` on a shared variable to iterate through the array.

You may hit some false sharing problems, as @DeadMG suggests, but quite possibly not. If you do have false sharing then yet another approach is to stride across larger sub-arrays.  Essentially the increment (i.e. stride) passed to `InterlockedIncrement()` would be greater than one.

The bottom line is that the way to make the code faster is to remove both the the critical section (and hence the contention on it) and the `Sleep(1)`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i will have a look at InterlockedIncrement(). however as i understand it, this will let the worker-threads share their load better. it's not clear to me how i get rid of the Sleep(1) and its loop though. or to put it another way: how does InterlockedIncrement() help me communicating more efficiently with my workers?

Comment: it allows you to iterate across all the cells without a lock.